# Retrieving data from multiple tables and listing them in a list

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having some problems retrieving data from two tables and then listing them. I'd like to list the user's feed posts and their likes activity all in one.

- Feeds - Table for users posts
- Likes - Table for users likes (So when a use likes a post, a record is added to likes (Table `likes` contains `data` which contains the `feeds ID` of the post liked)

What I'm attempting to make: List BOTH feeds and user's Like activity in an ACTIVITY WALL.

So it should output like (ordered by timestamp desc):

- "THIS IS A POST by user A"
- Shows that user C liked user B's post
- "THIS IS A POST by user B"
- "THIS IS A POST by user L"
- Shows that user A liked user F's post
- "THIS IS A POST by user F"
- -and it goes on-

My current SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM feeds,likes WHERE feeds.deleted!=0 or likes.deleted!=0 ORDER BY feeds.timestamp, likes.timestamp
```

However, my problem is I have no idea how to link both tables, since the IDs in my 'feeds' differ from those in 'likes'

Comment: Do you have a `post_id` or `feed_id` in the table likes? it would be helpful if you post the columns on both tables.

Comment: Table `likes` contains `data` which contains the `feed post ID` of the post liked

Comment: You should supply the table schemas to be helped better ;)

Comment: Whoops, should have done that! I'll keep that in mind next time! Thanks @Darren ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To combine the two sets, you can use a **`UNION ALL`** set operator.

Something like this:

```
SELECT f.timestamp    AS `timestamp`
     , 'feed'         AS `src`
     , f.feed_id      AS `id`
     , f.feed_content AS `content`
  FROM feeds f
 WHERE f.deleted!=0
 UNION ALL
SELECT l.timestamp    AS `timestamp`
     , 'like'         AS `src`
     , l.like_id      AS `id`
     , l.note         AS `content`
  FROM likes l
 WHERE l.deleted!=0
 ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Note the the queries (on either side of the `UNION ALL` operator) need to match, in terms of the number of columns returned, and the datatype of each column.

To accommodate differences, such as extra columns returned from one table, but not from the other,  you can add literal expressions in place of the "missing" columns.

The return of the extra `src` column is one way we can use to distinguish which query a row was returned by. It's not mandatory to return such a column, but it's something I often find useful. (The `src` column could be removed from each query, if it's not useful for your use case.)

Note that it's also possible to combine the results from more than two queries in this way, we'd just add another `UNION ALL` and another query.

The column names in the combined resultset are determined from the first query. The column names and aliases in the second query are ignored.

The `ORDER BY` applies to the entire set, and follows the last select.

Comment: This answers the question "how do I combine rows returned from two tables into a single set". For large sets, there is performance implication of the sort operation (to satisfy the `ORDER BY`). An alternative design would have a single table with the timestamps of the feeds and likes; and that would enable the ORDER BY to be satisfied using the index, rather than a "Using filesort" operation. But, that's really an answer to a question that wasn't asked. Another alternative would be to run the two queries separately, order the results from each by timestamp, and have client do the merge process

Comment: Thanks for your very informative answer! All working well now! Last question, how would I go about doing a union for three tables?

Comment: To combine the results from a third SELECT, just add, immediately prior to the `ORDER BY`, another `UNION ALL` set operator followed by another `SELECT` statement. The number of columns/expressions returned and the datatype of each column/expression returned has to match the previous SELECT(s).

Answer (score 0):

Query should be linked via postID 
F=feeds table, L=likes table, U1=usertable linked to owned feeds, U2=usertable linked to likes table

```
 SELECT F.postTitle+' posted by '+ U1.username,'liked by'+U2.username  
 FROM likes L
 LEFT JOIN feeds F on (F.postID=L.postID)
 LEFT JOIN users U1 on (U1.userID=F.userID) 
 LEFT JOIN users U2 on (U2.userID=L.userID) 
 ORDER BY L.date,L.postID DESC
```

Comment: I don't think this query returns the resulset specified by OP. This won't return separate rows for posts and likes. Also, the `+` operator is MySQL addition operator, and the expressions will be evaluated in a numeric context. For string concatenation, we'd typically use the `CONCAT` function.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `SELECT * FROM feeds,likes...` you are implicitly CROSS JOINing both tables. The engine will combine every record in each table with every record in the other. That is far from what you want.

I don't think you should be "linking" both tables, either. What you need, roughly speaking, is to get every post and every like, and then order that big set according to timestamps.

It sounds more like a UNION between two queries, and an ORDER BY applied to the whole UNION. UNIONs are never easy on the eye, by the way...

The thing with UNIONs is that both sub-queries need to return the same amount of columns. Not knowing exactly which columns you have, I'll show you one possible solution:

```
SELECT activity, timestamp FROM (
   ( SELECT CONCAT(u.name,' posted ',f.content) as activity, timestamp
     FROM user u
     JOIN feed f on (f.user_id=u.id)
     WHERE f.deleted!=0
   ) UNION
   ( SELECT CONCAT(u.name, ' liked a post by ',u2.name) as activity, timestamp
     FROM user u
     JOIN likes l on (l.user_id=u.id)
     JOIN feed f on (l.feed_id=f.id)
     JOIN user u2 on (f.user_id=u2.id)
     WHERE l.deleted!=0
   )
) as whole_result
ORDER by timestamp desc
```

You should, of course, modify this to match your structure.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The inline views aren't strictly necessary. The `UNION ALL` set operator would avoid the overhead of `UNION` operation which identifies and removes duplicate rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it's better to use 3rd table, say, "actions", and insert to it real actions. Then just select rows from this table, joined to "posts" & "users" table.

When user posts articles, o likes an article, insert corresponding row to "actions" table.

actions table:

```
|id|action_name|user_id|post_id|   date   |
 1   posted        3      3      5/7/2014
 2   liked         5      3      5/7/2014
 3   liked         4      3      6/7/2014
 4   posted        5      6      7/7/2014
 5   liked         3      6      7/7/2014

SELECT user_name a, post_title b, action_name c FROM actions c LEFT JOIN users a ON a.id=c.user_id LEFT JOIN posts b ON b.id = c.post_id ORDER BY c.date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Then, in loop, choose how to display this data, according to "action_name".
In such way you can expand your wall for other activities, +use indexes for better database performance.